# get element with two classes asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to select all the elements that have the two classes p1 and clicked.
I want the intersection with two classes.
My first class in cycle from model:

```
<div class="links">
       //cycle 
      <td>
         <a>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].P1, new { @class = "p1" })</a>
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].P1)
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

My second class in Click event:

```
$('.links a').click(function() {
     if(clicked)
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     else
       $(this).removeClass('clicked');
});
```

And then In button click:

```
$('.dobet').click(function() {
  // this I need to select element with two classes
});
```

I tried this:

```
$('.p1.clicked')
$(".p1").filter(".clicked")
document.querySelectorAll('.p1.clicked')
```

and some other.... but there is always an empty array.
But when I select only one class everything is fine.
.p1 elements - amount 18 , .clicked - amount (1 or 2 or other).

Comment: The statement which you tried is correct. Can you show the Click event handler. `this` must be referencing to some other element

Comment: how you are able to click on hidden form field..? Please post your generated HTML structure.

Comment: @Satpal, I edited. This better?

Comment: Unfortunately 0 items....

Comment: Try once with `$('a.clicked .p1') `

Comment: Where is the variable `clicked` in your condition `if (clicked)` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $el = $("a");

$($el.hasClass('p1') && $el.hasClass('clicked'))
```

Comment: He wants elements with both classes, so he probably needs `&&` instead of `||`.